# How to test and deploy a web service on a local WLP using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, web-services, deployment, websphere-liberty, web-testing

I need help testing and deploying a web service on a local WebSphere Liberty (WLP) using Eclipse.

I have the following installed:

- [Eclipse 2022-12](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2022-12/r)
- [IBM Liberty Developer Tools 22.2](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-liberty-developer-tools)
- [WebSphere Liberty Profile (WLP) 21.0.0.11](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/6508852)

Can anyone help me identify and solve the issue?

Here is the web service in Eclipse:
[image: Web service in Eclipse]

When I test the web service with the **Web Services Explorer**, I was expecting to be able to browse methods in the web service and be able to call them with different inputs. But instead I got the below message in the browser:

> IWAB0379E Unable to open http://localhost:9080/CognosIDM/CognosIDMService?WSDL.
> IWAB0135E An unexpected error has occurred.
> WSDLException
> WSDLException: faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: java.io.FileNotFoundException: `http://localhost:9080/CognosIDM/CognosIDMService?WSDL`

[image: Testing in Web Services Explorer]

Here are my Eclipse IDE installation details:
[image: Eclipse IDE Installation Details]

Comment: At the time of this writing, the latest Eclipse release supported by [Liberty Developer Tools](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-liberty-developer-tools) is v4.23 (2022-03).  You should retry with a supported version.

Comment: Is your server up and running? Can you access that link ` http://localhost:9080/CognosIDM/CognosIDMService?WSDL` from web browser and see the WSDL? Also show what features do you have configured in your `server.xml`